# How to do multiprocessing in FastAPI

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn

While serving a FastAPI request, I have a CPU-bound task to do on every element of a list. I'd like to do this processing on multiple CPU cores.

What's the proper way to do this within FastAPI? Can I use the standard `multiprocessing` module? All the tutorials/questions I found so far only cover I/O-bound tasks like web requests.

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

### `async def` endpoint

You could use [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) with [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) to start function at a separate process.

```
@app.post("/async-endpoint")
async def test_endpoint():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, cpu_bound_func)  # wait result
```

### `def` endpoint

Since `def` endpoints are [run implicitly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/?h=%20threadpool#path-operation-functions) in a separate thread, you can use the full power of modules [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). Note that inside `def` function, `await` may not be used. Samples:

```
@app.post("/def-endpoint")
def test_endpoint():
    ...
    with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as p:
        result = p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

```
@app.post("/def-endpoint/")
def test_endpoint():
    ...
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
      results = executor.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

*Note*: *It should be remembered that creating a pool of processes in an endpoint, as well as creating a large number of threads, can lead to a slowdown in response as the number of requests increases.*

---

### Executing on the fly

The easiest and most native way to execute a function in a separate process and immediately wait for the results is to use the [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) with [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).

A pool, as in the example below, can be created when the application starts and do not forget to shutdown on application exit. The number of processes used in the pool can be set using the [max_workers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) `ProcessPoolExecutor` constructor parameter. If `max_workers` is `None` or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine.

The disadvantage of this approach is that the request handler (path operation) waits for the computation to complete in a separate process, while the client connection remains open. And if for some reason the connection is lost, then the results will have nowhere to return.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI

from calc import cpu_bound_func


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    app.state.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    yield
    app.state.executor.shutdown()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


async def run_in_process(fn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(app.state.executor, fn, *args)  # wait and return result


@app.get("/{param}")
async def handler(param: int):
    res = await run_in_process(cpu_bound_func, param)
    return {"result": res}
```

### Move to background

Usually, CPU bound tasks are executed in the background. FastAPI offers the ability to run [background tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) to be run **after** returning a response, inside which you can start and asynchronously wait for the result of your CPU bound task.

In this case, for example, you can immediately return a response of `"Accepted"` (HTTP code 202) and a unique task `ID`, continue calculations in the background, and the client can later request the status of the task using this `ID`.

`BackgroundTasks` provide some features, in particular, you can run several of them (including in dependencies). And in them you can use the resources obtained in the dependencies, which will be cleaned only when all tasks are completed, while in case of exceptions it will be possible to handle them correctly. This can be seen more clearly in this [diagram](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/#dependencies-with-yield-and-httpexception).

Below is an example that performs minimal task tracking. One instance of the application running is assumed.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from http import HTTPStatus

from fastapi import BackgroundTasks
from typing import Dict
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

from calc import cpu_bound_func


class Job(BaseModel):
    uid: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    status: str = "in_progress"
    result: int = None


app = FastAPI()
jobs: Dict[UUID, Job] = {}


async def run_in_process(fn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(app.state.executor, fn, *args)  # wait and return result


async def start_cpu_bound_task(uid: UUID, param: int) -> None:
    jobs[uid].result = await run_in_process(cpu_bound_func, param)
    jobs[uid].status = "complete"


@app.post("/new_cpu_bound_task/{param}", status_code=HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED)
async def task_handler(param: int, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    new_task = Job()
    jobs[new_task.uid] = new_task
    background_tasks.add_task(start_cpu_bound_task, new_task.uid, param)
    return new_task


@app.get("/status/{uid}")
async def status_handler(uid: UUID):
    return jobs[uid]


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    app.state.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    yield
    app.state.executor.shutdown()
```

### More powerful solutions

All of the above examples were pretty simple, but if you need some more powerful system for heavy distributed computing, then you can look aside message brokers `RabbitMQ`, `Kafka`, `NATS` and etc. And libraries using them like Celery.

Comment: But this way I don't have access to the result of cpu_bound_func to return, right?

Comment: In case of background executing yes, but I modified the answer for returning example.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to update a global `dict` inside `cpu_bound_func` which did not work using the code above. Hence I ran the function directly inside of `start_cpu_bound_task` (without `await` and `async`) and it works. Is there any downside to my solution?

Comment: That's not a good idea to start cpu bound function in the context of async coroutine. The most preferable is to use some interprocess communication (or cache, database) to supply state updates to the web server from the working process. The example above is just a strong simplification.

Comment: I tried this and ended up getting `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`

Comment: Yeah won't work on hypercorn/gunicorn and so on

Comment: I tried the above solution. However, the app crashes when the function in the process pool raises a custom Exception. This is undesirable. How to handle exceptions thrown by functions in the process pool?