# python endpoint starting a thread with locking

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi

I'm using FASTApi and trying to implement an endpoint, which starts a job. Once the job is started, the endpoint shall be "locked" until the previous job finished. So far its implemented like this:

```
myapp.lock = threading.Lock()

@myapp.get("/jobs")
def start_job(some_args):
    if myapp.lock.acquire(False):
        th = threading.Thread(target=job,kwargs=some_args)
        th.start()
        return "Job started"
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400,detail="Job already running.")
```

So, when the job gets started, a thread will be created using the method job:

```
def job(some_args):
    try:
        #doing some stuff, creating objects and writing to files
    finally:
        myapp.lock.release()
```

So far so good, the endpoint is working, starts a job and locks as long as the job is running.
But my problem is that the thread is still alive although the job "finished" and released the lock. I was hoping that the thread would close itself after execution. Maybe the problem is that myapp is keeping it alive? How can I stop it?

Comment: You cannot use blocking sync methods in an asynchronous application. I would suggest storing the status of the task, for example, in a global object (unless you are using multiple workers). And check it instead of hanging in a lock. Perhaps an example from here will be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169865/how-to-do-multiprocessing-in-fastapi/

Comment: Thanks @alex_noname, I figured out a solution. The easiest way for me was using BackgroundTasks from FastAPI.

Comment: @alex_noname as this is a synchronous view, FastAPI will automatically start a separate thread for it, so this is not an issue in this situation (the view is not blocking the async loop itself)

Comment: @hellothere consider posting your solution as an answer to this question, as it may help anyone who encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this kind of solution:

```
myapp.lock = False

@myapp.get("/jobs")
async def start_job(some_args, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    if not myapp.lock:
        background_tasks.add_task(job, some_args)
        return "Job started"
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400,detail="Job already running.")

def job(some_args):
    try:
        myapp.lock = True
        #doing some stuff, creating objects and writing to files
    finally:
        myapp.lock = False
```

Comment: Note: this will only work as long your ASGI Server only spawm one Fork (Worker).
As soons as it starts multiple they won't have access to each others variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue. I would like to block the request that want to change the state of a specific object (an object is a simulation in my case). I use PostgreSQL and have created the following

1. Table

```
    create table simulation_lock (simulation_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, is_locked BOOLEAN DEFAULT False);
```

2. Lock context:

```
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException

from fmr.database import SessionContext


class SimulationLock:

    def __init__(self, simulation_id: int):
        self._simulation_id = simulation_id
        self._was_acquired = False

    def __enter__(self):
        with SessionContext() as session:
            query = f"update simulation_lock set is_locked = true where " \
                    f"simulation_id = {self._simulation_id} " \
                    f"and is_locked = false returning is_locked;"
            result = session.execute(query).first()
            session.commit()

            if result is not None and result[0] is True:
                self._was_acquired = True
            else:
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=500, detail="Already some operations on the "
                                            "simulation are performed.")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self._was_acquired:
            with SessionContext() as session:
                query = f"update simulation_lock set is_locked = false " \
                        f"where simulation_id = {self._simulation_id};"
                session.execute(query)
                session.commit()
```

3. Endpoint:

```
@scenario_router.post(
    "/run"
)
async def run(
        run_scenario_request: RunScenarioRequest,
):
    with SimulationLock(run_scenario_request.scenario_id):
        run_scenario(run_scenario_request)
```