# FastAPI asynchronous background tasks blocks other requests?

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to run a simple background task in FastAPI, which involves some computation before dumping it into the database. However, the computation would block it from receiving any more requests.

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
db = Database()

async def task(data):
    otherdata = await db.fetch("some sql")
    newdata = somelongcomputation(data,otherdata) # this blocks other requests
    await db.execute("some sql",newdata)
   


@app.post("/profile")
async def profile(data: Data, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(task, data)
    return {}
```

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: If the computation is heavy and do not involve IO it is better to use multiprocessing.

Comment: i am using the docker fastapi for deployment it's using all cpu cores for the server by default. I dont want to use another service like celery as the product is still in prototyping phase and has no users.

Comment: @GaryOng Please have a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Your `task` is defined as `async`, which means fastapi (or rather starlette) will run it in the asyncio event loop.
And because `somelongcomputation` is synchronous (i.e. not waiting on some IO, but doing computation) it will block the event loop as long as it is running.

I see a few ways of solving this:

- Use more workers (e.g. `uvicorn main:app --workers 4`). This will allow up to 4 `somelongcomputation` in parallel.
- Rewrite your task to not be `async` (i.e. define it as `def task(data): ...` etc). Then starlette will run it in a separate thread.
- Use [`fastapi.concurrency.run_in_threadpool`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1066#issuecomment-612940187), which will also run it in a separate thread. Like so:

  ```py
  from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
  async def task(data):
      otherdata = await db.fetch("some sql")
      newdata = await run_in_threadpool(lambda: somelongcomputation(data, otherdata))
      await db.execute("some sql", newdata)
  ```

  - Or use [`asyncios`'s `run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) directly (which `run_in_threadpool` uses under the hood):

    ```py
    import asyncio
    async def task(data):
        otherdata = await db.fetch("some sql")
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        newdata = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: somelongcomputation(data, otherdata))
        await db.execute("some sql", newdata)
    ```

    You could even pass in a [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent%20futures%20processpoolexecutor#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) as the first argument to `run_in_executor` to run it in a separate process.
- Spawn a separate thread / process yourself. E.g. using [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).
- Use something more heavy-handed like celery. (Also mentioned in the fastapi docs [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#caveat)).

Comment: I am facing the same problem here and I wonder why not just using `asyncio.create_task(task(data))`? I am doing some tests and seems to be the solution.

Comment: You mean instead of using `BackgroundTasks`? Are you sure that works? Because `asyncio.create_task` will run the task (and therefore `somelongcomputation`) in the event loop, which will then be blocked, just like in the question. The reason that `run_in_threadpool` works is that it runs the computation in the underlying threadpool directly, sidestepping the event loop.

Comment: if not using `async` spawns another thread, isn't this better than using `async`?

Comment: @Crashalot depends on the situation. Have a look at some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435284/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-vs-asyncio-in-python-3, and maybe here: https://discuss.python.org/t/what-are-the-advantages-of-asyncio-over-threads/2112/6.

Comment: where would one need to pass ```concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor``` in exactly? In    ```newdata = await loop.run_in_executor(ProcessPoolExecutor(), lambda: somelongcomputation(data, otherdata))```?

Comment: @ben yep, have a look at the documenation for some examples (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

Comment: I don't think Threads are of any help here. Since Python doesn't utilize true Parallelism, spawning thread for heavy CPU computation will still hold the entire program. Use Proccesses instead.

Comment: I agree with Alexander, threads do not help for CPU bounded operations in python, but given the high number of votes here it makes me wonder if I miss something or not... @mihi - would love to here your thoughts here

Comment: @ShayTsadok Threads won't help with overall throughput, that is true. But using them does prevent blocking of other requests, as context switching between the threads still happens. They won't run in parallel, but rather interleaved.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3091).

Also in the example below, `my_model.function_b` could be any blocking function or process.

TL;DR

```py
from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool

@app.get("/long_answer")
async def long_answer():
    rst = await run_in_threadpool(my_model.function_b, arg_1, arg_2)
    return rst
```

Answer (score 1):

If your task is CPU bound you could use multiprocessing, there is way to do that with Background task in FastAPI:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63171013

Although you should consider to use something like Celery if there are lot of cpu-heavy tasks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a example of Background Task To FastAPI

```py
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
x = [1]  # a global variable x


@app.get("/")
def hello():
    return {"message": "hello", "x": x}

async def periodic():
    while True:
        # code to run periodically starts here
        x[0] += 1
        print(f"x is now {x}")
        # code to run periodically ends here
        # sleep for 3 seconds after running above code
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def schedule_periodic():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(periodic())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app)
```