# Background task in fastapi making blocking requests

Tags: fastapi, starlette

I have a resource intensive async method that i want to run as a background task. Example code for it looks like this:

```
@staticmethod
async def trigger_task(id: str, run_e2e: bool = False):
    try:
        add_status_for_task(id)
        result1, result2 = await task(id)
        update_status_for_task(id, result1, result2)
    except Exception:
        update_status_for_task(id, 'FAIL')


@router.post("/task")
async def trigger_task(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(EventsTrigger.trigger_task)
    return {'msg': 'Task submitted!'}
```

When i trigger this endpoint, I expect an instant output: `{'msg': 'Task submitted!'}`. But instead the api output is awaited till the task completes. I am following this documentation from [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/).

fastapi: v0.70.0
python: v3.8.10

I believe the issue is similar to what is described [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1313).
Request help in making this a non-blocking call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fastapi asynchronous background tasks blocks other requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599119/fastapi-asynchronous-background-tasks-blocks-other-requests)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI runs api-calls in serial instead of parallel fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion)

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned from the github issues,

- You can't use `async def` for task functions (Which will run in background.)
- As in background process you can't access the coroutine, So, your async/await will not  work.
- You can still try without async/await. If that also doesn't work then you should go for alternative.

**Alternative Background Solution**

- [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) is production ready task scheduler. So, you can easily configure and run the background task using `your_task_function.delay(*args, **kwargs)`
- **Note that,** Celery also doesn't support async in background task. So, whatever you need to write is sync code to run in background.

**Good Luck :)**

Comment: from fast api [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), we can actually use both async and normal methods.

Comment: Yes. But from the bug report/issues I proposed a way. It's may not correct. Whatever!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you seem to have oversimplified your example so it is a little hard to tell what is going wrong.

But the important question is: are `add_status_for_task()` or `update_status_for_task()` blocking? Because if they are (and it seems like that is the case), then obviously you're going to have issues. When you run code with async/await all the code inside of it needs to be async as well.

This would make your code look more like:

```py
async def trigger_task(id: str, run_e2e: bool = False):
    try:
        await add_status_for_task(id)
        result1, result2 = await task(id)
        await update_status_for_task(id, result1, result2)
    except Exception:
        await update_status_for_task(id, 'FAIL')


@router.post("/task/{task_id}")
async def trigger_task(task_id: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(EventsTrigger.trigger_task, task_id)
    return {'msg': 'Task submitted!'}
```

Answer (score -2):

How are you running your app?

According to the uvicorn docs its running with 1 worker by default, which means only one process will be issued simultaneously.
Try configuring your uvicorn to run with more workers.
https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/

```
$ uvicorn example:app --port 5000 --workers THE_AMOUNT_OF_WORKERS
or
uvicorn.run("example:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, workers=THE_AMOUNT_OF_WORKERS)
```

Comment: This does not seems to be a correct approach because with this, if i run 4 workers and have 20 users, then at a time only 4 of them will be able to run their task because this was a blocking call.

Comment: It should handle it right if you are using async await in python right. Check that the thing u do support async work. 
I would recommend u to think about using python celery, my team use it to run async tasks for a large number of users. Depends on your amount of users and on the amount of time required to complete the task i would recommend scaling your service.