# FastAPI backgroud task block other api request

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, background-task

It's seem like [fastapi asynchronous background tasks blocks other requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599119/fastapi-asynchronous-background-tasks-blocks-other-requests) but it seems my problem is a bit different

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
db = Database()

async def task(data):
    otherdata = await db.fetch("some sql")
    await db.execute("insert otherdata sql",otherdata) # this blocks other api requests when excute'time too long. 

@app.post("/profile")
async def profile(data: Data, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(task, data)
    return {}
```

But when not define async it will not block other api request.
(https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/)

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI
from time import sleep

app = FastAPI()
db = Database()

def task(data):
     for x in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        print(x)

@app.post("/profile")
async def profile(data: Data, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(task, data)
    return {}
```

--> My prolem is When I excute sql (long execution time), i must be using async/await but using with background task of fast api, it will block other api request. So Is there any way I define my task is sync and excute sql by async/await.