# FastAPI run heavy compute task asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, fastapi

Hi all I have an issue with running heavy compute task on fastapi endpoint.

```py
@app.post("/run/")
async def run_cases(data: List[schemas.TestID], db: orm.Session = Depends(services.get_db)):
try:
   CONTAINER.create()
   tcm = TestManager(CONTAINER, data) # this is a Class that's does all my data parsing

   case_manager_data = tcm.run()
        
   for x in case_manager_data.result():
       services.create_result(db=db, result=schemas.Result(**x))

except Exception as ex:
    raise ex

return True
```

This is my "stock" endpoint and I'm passing data to it that is computed with class TestManager.

However, when I'm sending this data, the whole app stops until I get the result from *tcm*. I can't go to any other endpoint etc... (all my endpoints are created with **async def**)

So I've tried

```py
from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
data = await run_in_threadpool(tcm.run())

import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, tcm.run())

from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
await run_in_threadpool(tcm.run())
```

but every time behavior stays the same, application is blocked when running tcm.run()

What Im doing wrong?

posts that I've been researching on
[fisrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599119/fastapi-asynchronous-background-tasks-blocks-other-requests) [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169865/how-to-do-multiprocessing-in-fastapi/63171013#63171013) [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion)

Comment: Please don't use `//` comments in Python, it messes up the syntax highlighting here, for example.

Comment: If you want to run asynchronously and run heavy jobs, use `BackgroundTasks` or [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is omit `()` when supplying `tcm.run` to the `run_in_threadpool`.

```py
from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
case_manager_data = await run_in_threadpool(tcm.run)
```

This way you're passing the function `tcm.run` to the threadpool, and there it gets executed. Adding `()` means you're calling the function inline in the code itself.