# How to run many workers of FastAPI app if I have a huge in-memory cache

Tags: python, fastapi, gunicorn

I'm running FastAPI app using gunicorn that has only one synchronous endpoint with CPU-bound task. I'm using third party library that reads data from file and saves it into a memory for faster access and this data is huge(around 8gb). I wanted to increase number of workers to be able to handle more requests per second and found out that each worker is a separate process and can't share any resources with others.

If I want to run my app with 4 workers I need to have a machine with 8*4=32gb RAM. My goal is to make my app to be able to serve more requests, in current situation I can run only 1 worker which is insufficient.

What is a workaround for my case? I don't have much expirience in python and FastAPI so I might be missing something.

I was thinking of using a distributed cache(like Redis) so any worker will be able to access it. But this approach requires to make many modifications in the third party library that I'm using so I don't want to put so much effort and time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the answer for this question might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169865/how-to-do-multiprocessing-in-fastapi

Comment: You can use something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613757/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Its always a bad idea to process a large chunk of data in the web server.

The best and most optimized solution will be not to process that data in the server itself and offload it forward.

The most optimized solution will be to create an **Event-Based Architecture**.

If I were in your place, I'd do one of the following,

1. Using [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to create a task queue and give the data to celery to process that data separately in an async manner.
2. Using Apache Kafka or RabbitMQ, you can do the same.
3. If you are using any cloud provider, use their tools, like AWS you forward that data to a Lambda to process that.